# A "convergence theorem" in measure theory?

Tags: integration, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $A_n$ ($n \in \mathbb{N}$) be a sequence of measurable subsets of some measure space with $A_1 \subseteq A_2 \subseteq...$ and let $A:= \bigcup_{n < \infty} A_n$. Let $f:A \to \mathbb{R}$ a measurable map which is integrable on every $A_n$. Moreover, assume that the limit
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{A_n} f d\mu$$
exists (and is a real number). Can we conclude that $f$ is integrable on $A$ and that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{A_n} f d\mu=\int_A f d\mu\phantom{aa}\text{?}$$

The motivation for the question is a bit tedious to explain in detail but I just found some sources (i.e. handwritten lecture notes) where this type of inference seems to be implicitly used without any explanation. The problem in these sources is that the classical convergence theorems from measure theory cannot be applied in an obvious way since the integrals $\int_{A_n} |f| d\mu$ have no (obvious) upper bound. So, I was just wondering whether the above might be true.

Comment: What sources???

Comment: @user21820, some handwritten lecture notes.

Comment: I suggest stating that next time, because "sources" tends to suggest "published articles", which is completely different from "lecture notes".

Comment: @user21820, ok. I edited my question.

Comment: That's great! If you like we can delete the now redundant comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the real line with Lebesgue measure take $A_n=(-n,n), A=\mathbb R$ and $f(x)=x$ for  a counter-example.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is essentially the same as saying that if the improper Riemann integral $\int_0^\infty f(t)\,dt:=\lim_{x\to\infty}\int_0^x f(t)\,dt$ converges, then $\int_{[0,\infty)}\lvert f(t)\rvert\,dt<\infty$. This is famously not the case. [For instance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_integral), see $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}x\,dx=\frac\pi2$ and $\int_0^\infty\left\lvert \frac{\sin x}x\right\rvert\,dx=\infty$.

The claim holds for $f\ge0$ by Beppo Levi.

Comment: It seems "Beppo Levi" is what I learned as "monotone convergence theorem".

Comment: @GEdgar It is.${}$